# Persisting sessions across subdomains in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Using 5.0

in config/session.php I have set `'domain' => '.example.com'` but it is not working. I cannot persist a session on even one domain like this.

My site has many subdomains:

```
vancouver.example.com
newyork.example.com
```

etc... they are hosted on the same server and are the same Laravel app (share the same storage directory)

I login with the correct credentials, upon which the app redirects to another page on the site, and I have no session at that point. `var_dump(Auth::user())` shows `null` even though I logged in with the correct credentials.

`storage/framework/sessions` shows 14 different files there, they are all for me and I cleared them out before I started testing this.

I'll attach my AuthController@postLogin method below, which works fine if session.php `'domain' => null`

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email', 'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    if ($this->auth->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember')))     {
        Session::flash('message', 'You are now logged in.');
        Session::flash('status', 'success');

        if (str_contains($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], '?goto=')) {
            $params = explode('?', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])[1];
            $target = explode('=', $params)[1];
        } else {
            $target = '/';
        }

        return redirect($target);
    }

    return redirect($this->loginPath())
                ->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'))
                ->withErrors([
                    'email' => $this->getFailedLoginMessage(),
                ]);
}
```

Comment: I had the same problem before and just needed to clear the browser cache.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Figured it out. Update `domain => '.example.com'` in session.php and clear the cookies for the site in question.

Comment: I did the same but not working for me.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39714443/laravel-5-athentication-in-subdomain-is-not-working

Comment: do you mean browser cookies?

Comment: Note: If you do this solution after an unsuccesful attempt, don't forget to delete all existing cookies on all subdomains.

Comment: In Laravel 5.4, this can now be configurate in .env file with `SESSION_DOMAIN`.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But what is the difference between `domain` and `path` at `config/session.php`?

Comment: Works for me on L5.8. It work on localhost, too. Both domain and subdomain(s) are handled by the same application.

Comment: How to clear a cookie on the user side? my clients already have cookies using example.com!

Answer (score 22):

@gadss

you need to add session table like this

```
php artisan session:table

composer dump-autoload

php artisan migrate
```

and change .env to
`SESSION_DRIVER=database`

also modify config/session.php

`'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'database')` and

```
'domain' => '.yourdomain.com'
```

after that clear your browser's cache and cookies.

Comment: @DucChi glad to help.

Answer (score 10):

You'll need to update the session configuration to persist the session in domain-wide including subdomains. Follow the steps given below.

1. Go to **`config/session.php`** and update the **`domain`** with prefix **`.`** as **`config => '.your-domain.com'`**.
2. Then clear your application cache, Open the Chrome DevTool and Go to **Application > Application > Clear Storage**. You'll need to clear out the previous **cookies** also.
3. run artisan command **`php artisan config:cache`** or **`php artisan config:clear`** to drop previously cached laravel application configs.

If you are using **database** as the session driver, You need to create a session table for that. run command **`php artisan session:table`** to generate the session table migration and then migrate it using **`php artisan migrate`**. Then perform the three steps given above.

Comment: Clearing storage is fine for developers, but what are users supposed to do when we push to production?

Comment: You'll need to forget all cookies, if you have the site in production then you can deploy something to clear all the client cookies on request.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Cleared sessions, config and cache still not working. Not sure what cookies we are supposed to clear for the user

Comment: You'll need to clear the session cookie to avoid old session that was created with old configuration.

Comment: That makes sense. I have cleared the sessions in storage/framework/sessions. How do we remove it locally for the user in the browser?

Comment: You don't have control over there, as you've cleared the session directory on the server-side, It should be fine now.

Comment: Would like to confirm if protocol (http://  or http://) is need or just directly the domain name

Comment: You can use just a domain name without protocol, the session key itself says to use `domain` only :)

Comment: not working. Can it working in laravel >= 5.5 ?

Answer (score 9):

With Laravel 8 it becomes more simplier :

Add **SESSION_DOMAIN** to your *.env* file :

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=.yourdomain.tld
```

Clear configuration cache :

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Delete your browser sessions cookies, then session become shared between all your subdomains.

In my case I used to AutoLogin user to subdomain once account is created on www. domain. Worked fine.

Comment: not working :( I'm using laravel 5.5

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried storing the sessions in the database, memcached, or redis instead of in files? I had a similar situation to yours and storing sessions in the database solved the issue for me.

For some reason Laravel's session driver doesn't handle cross domain sessions correctly when using the file driver.

Comment: yes I am using the file driver, I will try using database instead tonight. thanks.

Comment: @AnthonyVipond Did you try using the database? What were your results?

Comment: Thanks!  Laravel 4.2 handles subdomains with file sessions perfectly, but on Laravel 5.2 I had to switch to database session storage.

Comment: @BrokenBinary i want to Keep the same session in different subdomains.. how can i do that with laravel

Comment: I found that I had to manually remove the sessions stored in `storeage\framework\sessions` as well as clearing the cookie cache.  Then it worked ok.

Answer (score 3):

If someone still gets the problem with subdomain cookie. Try to change Session Cookie Name in config/session.php

Answer (score 0):

> If someone needs to sync session in subdomains with ***different** laravel application **sharing same database***

Follow all the instructions of [@Kiran Maniya](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59213411/14755596)
Then you have to keep same application name in order to get same session name. Or just change the cookie config in `config/session.php`

You can hardcode it if keeping same name is not possible.

```
'cookie' => env(
    'SESSION_COOKIE',
    Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
)
```

to something like:

```
'cookie' => env(
    'SESSION_COOKIE',
    'session_sharing_application_session'
)
```