# Login in another subdomain after registration Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, authentication, subdomain

In Laravel 5.3 the default `RegisterController` uses the `RegistersUsers` trait. And in the register method we have `$this->guard()->login($user);`. This looks good, however my problem is:

I'm using subdomains to each account like: *customer1.example.com*, *customer2.example.com*, etc. And I have another subdomain to the registration that is *signup.example.com*.

What I need and that I don't found the solution is when a customer create a new account in *signup.example.com* will be logged in and redirected to *customer1.example.com*.

The redirection is working as expected (changing the `$redirectTo` property). However, when the user registration is completed successfully he will be logged in signup.example.com instead *customer1.example.com*

How can I do it?

**EDIT**
I already tried to change app.config from 'null' to '.example.com'. This works, but not as expected. Because, in this case you will be logged in all subdomains and I only that you'll be logged in a specific subdomain.

Also tried to set the domain config dynamically in 'create' method of register controller like config(['session.domain' => 'customer1.example.com']); but this doesn't work. In this case the user doesn't will be logged in.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30338518/persisting-sessions-across-subdomains-in-laravel-5 ? (cross sub domain session)

Comment: Thank you. However, this is not what I need. Because I don't want to be logged in in all subdomains, only in the one that users created at the registration. So, if users choose a subdomain "thisismysubdomain.example.com" I only want that he will be logged in this subdomain. Thans.