# same authentication on different sub-domains in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-authorization

consider `project.local` as the local address for my project
and for admins there's a sub-domain : `admin.project.local`
 both addresses are directed to the same `/public` folder and I've handled the routes like this:

```
 Route::group(['domain' => 'admin.project.local'], function () {
     // routes for admin (managed by AdminController)
 });

 Route::group(['domain' => 'project.local'], function () {
     // routes for users (managed by AppController)
 });
```

`AdminController` is using `auth.admin` middleware which check's for authentication and users permissions (if the user has admin access) 
`AppController` is using `auth` middleware which simply check's for authentication

so I was expecting two things:

1. the user without admin access would only be able to surf through `project.local`
2. the user with admin access would be able to surf through both `admin.project.local` and `project.local`

but the second one isn't happening , look's like `laravel` consider's completely separated authentications for different domains 
is that right or I'm missing something ?
how can I fix this so any logged-in user is considered logged-in in the whole project , no matter what the domain is ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Persisting sessions across subdomains in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30338518/persisting-sessions-across-subdomains-in-laravel-5)