# Authentication subdomain in laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have login page in url `http://account.my-website.com`, after authenticated I want user redirect to `http://dashboard.my-website.com`. I have already set `SESSION_DOMAIN=.my-website.com`, but in url `dashboard.my-website.com` it's not detected that I have authenticated, so I return to login page, but in  `http://account.my-website.com` I already logged in, endless redirect and error. How I achieve login in different subdomain for another subdomain in laravel, thanks.

Comment: I guess this answers your question. You need to change session driver to db. Check this link out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30338518/persisting-sessions-across-subdomains-in-laravel-5

Comment: Thanks, but why file session driver cannot achieve this thing..?

Comment: I tried change to database driver, but now the result after login is `302 Found`, then back to login page again.