# Multiple SESSION_DOMAIN on Laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, session, cookies

I am developing a Laravel 5.8 app with this format:

- 2 authentication tables ("Users" and "Clients")
- 3 subdomains ( "app.mysite.com", "dashboard.mysite.com", "client.mysite.com" )

The "clients" will access only the pages from "client.mysite.com" subdomain.
The "users" will access the pages from "app.mysite.com" and "dashboard.mysite.com" subdomains, so i need to persist the cookies between then.

How i can do this? Is there a multiple SESSION_DOMAIN system in Laravel?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Persisting sessions across subdomains in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30338518/persisting-sessions-across-subdomains-in-laravel-5)

Answer (score 4):

use `.mysite.com` to include all subdomains, note that there is a `dot` before mysite.com.

```
'domain' => .mysite.com
```

Comment: Hi @shamaseen, I have different scenario, the session should be different every subdomain it is possible?

Comment: @ClintonCanarias you can make a middleware to change the domain based on the subdomain you are in, and assign that middleware to the routes you want

Comment: The concept of my system is that some users are only allowed to login to a specific domain. i.e., user 1 should be able to login to subdomain1.site.com, and user 2 can only login to subdomain2.site.com.

Comment: @ClintonCanarias Yes, you can achieve that using route middleware. You can even achieve it using auth guard middleware if these users are on different guards.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to build a multiple auth system for each user model (Admin, Customer...) by using multiple guards:
https://medium.com/@sagarmaheshwary31/laravel-multiple-guards-authentication-setup-and-login-2761564da986

For multiple domaine there is several ways to do this

- Multi tenant: [Tenacy with Laravel](https://tenancy.dev/)
- Group your routes by domain:

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'www.domain.com'], function(){
        //...
    });

    Route::group(['domain' => 'mobile.domain.com'], function(){
        //...
    });

    Route::group(['domain' => 'admin.domain.com'], function(){
        //...
    });
```

Look this: https://medium.com/@maxkostinevich/how-to-build-multi-domain-laravel-application-e6d87d5e507b

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I think this system only works with a single auth table :(

Answer (score 1):

Go to config/session.php

replace this line

> `'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),`

by

```
'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', '.yourdomain.td'),
```

You can also do it by adding this key in your .env file

```
SESSION_DOMAIN='yourdomaine.td'
```

Don't forget to run these commands

```
php artisan config:cache
```

and

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

Answer (score -1):

By default, the session is configured using the `.env` file. You can override it in your `config/session.php` file:

```
'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),
```

change to something like:

```
'domain' => $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],
```

Comment: This creates a big security issue because any domain (even other websites) can access your session. 
SERVER_NAME means "any domain used to connect".

Comment: If the webserver is incorrectly configured, I understand it is possible. However, the server should be correctly configured and not return a website for requests on a domain the website is not configured for.

Comment: Strongly not recommend, this arises a lot of security risks