# Laravel 6 session cookies not being set for base domain in Safari 13

Tags: php, laravel, session, cookies, safari

In the Laravel framework, setting session cookies on the root domain level is not working in safari 13.0.3, but works in Safari 12, Chrome, and Firefox.

Because cookies are not being set, each page refresh creates a new session and logging in does not work.

I am using the default laravel setup aside from session behavior in app/session.php, where I've changed the SESSION_DOMAIN to the root domain ('.example.test') and set the SESSION_DRIVER to 'database' (following advice from [Persisting sessions across subdomains in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30338518/persisting-sessions-across-subdomains-in-laravel-5)).

The cookies get set in safari 13 when the domain is set to the full url (subdomain.example.com) but not when changed to the root url (.example.com)

In the Safari debugging tools, I can see the request headers being set and going through, but the cookies never make it into storage.

Network request headers/cookies:
[image: Network request headers/cookies]

Things I have tried:

- Tried with and without the driver as database
- Changing the session cookie name, the samesite behavior, and the secure behavior in session.php
- adding slash to end of session domain as well as removing the first .
- Incognito / Private browsing mode (doesn't change behavior, still works in chrome but not safari)
- Isolating issue as well as upgrading to latest laravel version (originally noticed on 5.6, still happening in latest release 6.6)
- Turning off cookie encryption

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't test on safari 13, but my guess is the recent [RFC 6265 (2011)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.1.2.3):

> The Domain attribute specifies those hosts to which the cookie will be sent.  For example, if the value of the Domain attribute is "example.com", the user agent will include the cookie in the Cookie header when making HTTP requests to example.com, [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), and [www.corp.example.com](http://www.corp.example.com).  (Note that a leading %x2E ("."), if present, is ignored even though that character is not permitted, but a trailing %x2E ("."), if present, will cause the user agent to ignore the attribute.)  If the server omits the Domain attribute, the user agent will return the cookie only to the origin server.

Set `SESSION_DOMAIN` to the root domain `example.test` without the trailing `.`

Note that a domain without the trailing `.` is invalid in the old [RFC 2109 (1997)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2109), some very old browsers may not accept the cookie. Safari 12 and other popular browsers will accept the cookie because of the [RFC 2965 (2000)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2965):

> If an explicitly specified value does not start with a dot, the user agent supplies a leading dot

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I gave it a shot without the leading/trailing . and unfortunately it is still not accepting it.

Comment: I was able to test on safari 13.0.3 (macOS High Sierra), `.example.test` works perfectly. Something is wrong in the client side, disable all extensions, unregister the service worker if you have it, clear all app cache... According to the Network request image you posted, the browser should send the received cookie.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time! It's super helpful to know it is likely on my end

Comment: I believe this approved answer does not solve the issue. I think I have found the more general problem related to cookies not being shared across subdomains for non-tld .test domains, Safari 13 and (perhaps) certificates. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62023857/sharing-cookies-across-test-sub-domains-in-safari-13-not-possible