# Laravel 7 Weird Logout Issue

Tags: php, laravel, razorpay

I have just finished a Laravel 7 app. Upon after finalising payments, I am now having weird issue. I send LOGGED IN USER to payment gateway, the user pays and gateway sends back the user to website as a POST request. But the website response action is never called. Since it is under **auth** middleware, the user is I don't know how LOGGED OUT and sent to the login screen instead.

The route definition is as follows:

```
<?php

Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {

    // This sends the user to gateway
    Route::post('subscription', 'SubscriptionController@renew')->name('subscription.renew');

    // Gateway sends the user back here
    Route::post('subscription/process', 'SubscriptionController@process')->name('subscription.process');
});
```

Inspecting network tab about hops is as follows:

```
POST http://localhost:8000/subscription -> 302 << gateway >>
<< gateway >> -> POST http://localhost:8000/subscription/process -> 302 http://localhost:8000/login
```

In the response where the app sends to http://localhost:8000/login, the headers have `laravel_session` cookie as required.

But the action http://localhost:8000/subscription/process is never called and user is logged out. Never had such issues upto Laravel 6 with same payment gateway.

Moreover, I also added below URL to `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware as at first, it was throwing 419.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as Middleware;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    protected $except = [
        '/subscription/process',
    ];
}
```

Can anybody shed some light on what could be the reason?

Comment: Could be similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30338518/persisting-sessions-across-subdomains-in-laravel-5

Comment: The requests aren't cross-domain in my case. It's on single domain.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found out! It was due to `SameSite=Lax` set by default in **Laravel 7** session cookie as in https://github.com/laravel/laravel/commit/2913a55d87461fabe94907c5728d7a9451bcae80 commit.