# Laravel multi app with auto single sign on

Tags: laravel, authentication, single-sign-on

I have a `main.com` and `A.main.com`, `B.main.com`, when user sign in/sign up in `main.com`, and that user go to `A.main.com/B.main.com` that user should be auto login. how can i do this.

Im trying sso with auto login

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30338518/persisting-sessions-across-subdomains-in-laravel-5

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.